# How do I click double click on the row of the table with the Karate framework

Tags: karate

```
And def rowText = text("//*[@id='id-table']/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]")   
* mouse(rowText).doubleClick()
```

I want click on row of the table but in Karate you can't click on text.